# spark sql round and bround

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am confused how round and bround is working in spark sql.

```
scala> spark.sql("select round(1.5, 0), bround(1.5, 0)").show()
+-------------+--------------+
|round(1.5, 0)|bround(1.5, 0)|
+-------------+--------------+
|            2|             2|
+-------------+--------------+


scala> spark.sql("select round(2.5, 0), bround(2.5, 0)").show()
+-------------+--------------+
|round(2.5, 0)|bround(2.5, 0)|
+-------------+--------------+
|            3|             2|
+-------------+--------------+


scala> spark.sql("select round(3.5, 0), bround(3.5, 0)").show()
+-------------+--------------+
|round(3.5, 0)|bround(3.5, 0)|
+-------------+--------------+
|            4|             4|
+-------------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. **round**

> Rounding mode to round towards {@literal "nearest neighbor"}
>       unless both neighbors are equidistant, in which case round up.
>       Behaves as for {@code `RoundingMode.UP`} if the discarded
>       fraction is > 0.5; otherwise, behaves as for
>       {@code `RoundingMode.DOWN`}.  Note that this is the rounding
>       mode commonly taught at school.

Examples :

```
input=5.5 output=6
input=2.5 output=3
input=1.6 output=2
input=1.1 output=1
input=1.0 output=1
input=-1.0 output=-1
input=-1.1 output=-1
input=-1.6 output=-2
input=-2.5 output=-3
input=-5.5 output=-6
```

2. **bround**

> Rounding mode to round towards the {@literal "nearest neighbor"}
>       unless both neighbors are equidistant, in which case, round
>       towards the even neighbor.  Behaves as for
>       {@code `RoundingMode.HALF_UP`} if the digit to the left of the
>       discarded fraction is odd; behaves as for
>       {@code `RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN`} if it's even.  Note that this
>       is the rounding mode that statistically minimizes cumulative
>       error when applied repeatedly over a sequence of calculations.
>       It is sometimes known as {@literal "Banker's rounding,"} and is
>       chiefly used in the USA.  This rounding mode is analogous to
>       the rounding policy used for {@code float} and {@code double}
>       arithmetic in Java.

Examples

```
    input=5.5 output=6
    input=2.5 output=2
    input=1.6 output=2
    input=1.1 output=1
    input=1.0 output=1
    input=-1.0 output=-1
    input=-1.1 output=-1
    input=-1.6 output=-2
    input=-2.5 output=-2
    input=-5.5 output=-6
```

Answer (score 3):

`round` uses HALF_UP, while `bround` uses HALF_EVEN (**b**anker's) rounding [[source](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.4.5/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.scala#L2000)].

Answer (score 2):

`bround` always rounded to decimal places to `nearest` even integer value.

**bround(expr, d)** - Returns expr rounded to d decimal places using HALF_EVEN rounding mode.

`round` always rounded to decimal places to next value either `even` or `odd` value.

**round(expr, d)** - Returns expr rounded to d decimal places using HALF_UP rounding mode.

Answer (score 1):

This is gaussian rounding. Aka bround will round to the nearest even number. The [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/R/bround.html) will speak further about what this concept entails.